How to append data from input() into a numpy array?
I want to take 5 numbers from the user throught the input() and append them to a numpy array. I have the following code:
import numpy as np

X = [int(i) for i in input().split()]
X = np.array(X)
print(X)

When I run the above program I get the following output
[12345]

But if I have the following code
import numpy as np
X = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
print(X)

I get the following output
[1 2 3 4 5]

I want to take input from the user using the input() and append it to a numpy array and when I use the print function on the array I get the above output. How can I do that in my code?

What did you input?

What did the user input? '12345' or '1 2 3 4 5'?  Did you examine the list before making an array?

my input is 12345

What does input().split() do?

Then .split() will not work. It splits on whitespace.

You aren't doing any 'append', to array or list.  You are making an array from a list (comprehension)

Does this answer your question? How do I split a string into a list of characters?

Either you need to use different code if the user should input 12345, or if you want to use the same code, the user needs to input 1 2 3 4 5.

@mkrieger1 as you can see in the code I want them integer not string

You need to split the string '12345' into the list of characters '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', which you then need to convert to integers individually, that's what I meant by suggesting that other question. You could just omit .split() to achieve that.
